# Trying to read excel but getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException if user deletes row

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core

Using openxml to read an excel file and write data into a database. 
Data from the spreadsheet is stored in a data table and then mapped into a object array. The problem is: if a user deletes a row in the excel file I get the exception 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index' when reading the file.

To counter this, I have tried checking if the cell value is null, if so then take it as an empty string. However, the error occurs when I reach the 9th column in the last "deleted" row (8 columns out of 10 are taken as an empty string).

```cs
IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

foreach (Row row in rows) 
                {
                    DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < tempRow.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
                    {
                       //I get the exception here  
                        Cell c = row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i);

                        if (c.CellValue != null)
                        {
                            tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                        }
                        else if (c.CellValue == null )
                        {
                            tempRow[i] = "";
                        }
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);

                }
```

Comment: on which line of code it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by checking if we are within the range of the available columns in the row. Also checking if the first cell in the row is empty, discarding it if it is.

```cs
foreach (Row row in rows) 
                {
                    bool isEmpty = false;
                    DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < tempRow.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count())
                        {
                            Cell c = row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i);

                            if (c.CellValue != null)
                            {
                                tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    isEmpty = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else tempRow[i] = "";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tempRow[i] = "";
                        }
                    }

                    if (isEmpty) continue;

                    dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);

                }
```